# IO.directorynotfound - Dynamical SqlConnection string

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, io, sqlconnection

I have got this code which should read `path from app.Settings` but now I have value there and when I release this project as `.exe`  file and I try to install it on another computer after successful instalation I run it and it throws an error with `system.IO.directorynotfound` .

I thought that it can look something like this:

```
 private static string _ConnectionString;
 public static string ConnectionString {
    get {
        if (_ConnectionString == null) _ConnectionString = FunctionToDynamicallyCreateConnectionstring();
        return _ConnectionString;
    }
 }
 private static string FunctionToDynamicallyCreateConnectionstring() {


    string path = Properties.Settings.Default.swPath;

    if (path != null) {
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(File.Open(path, FileMode.Open));

        SqlConnectionStringBuilder cb = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();


        cb.DataSource = DecodeFrom64(sr.ReadLine());
        cb.InitialCatalog = DecodeFrom64(sr.ReadLine());
        cb.UserID = DecodeFrom64(sr.ReadLine());
        cb.Password = DecodeFrom64(sr.ReadLine());


    }
    return cb.ToString();
 }
```

But it gives following error: `The name 'cb' does not exist in the current context` - yes I know why because it is not inside the arrange of If. But Im not sure how to improve it so if the path wasn't found on particular computer the program will normally continue until I set the right path.

Thank you everyone for your time and answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the cb.ToString outside the closing braces where is defined.

```
   private static string FunctionToDynamicallyCreateConnectionstring()
   {

        string path = Properties.Settings.Default.swPath;

        if (path != null)
        {
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(File.Open(path, FileMode.Open));

            SqlConnectionStringBuilder cb = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();


            cb.DataSource = DecodeFrom64(sr.ReadLine());
            cb.InitialCatalog = DecodeFrom64(sr.ReadLine());
            cb.UserID = DecodeFrom64(sr.ReadLine());
            cb.Password = DecodeFrom64(sr.ReadLine());
            return cb.ToString(); 
       }
       else
            return string.Empty
   }
```

Beware that the function requires a return of type string. So if your path is null, you need to supply an alternative return value. And handle that possibility in the calling code.....

Usually the connectionstring is a basic piece of configuration for every database application, so, if it is not configured correctly you have only two possibilities:

- Terminate your application with a warning to the user and ask for
  support assistance
- Show a dialog box where your user inserts the needed informations.

The second approach requires a bit of knowledge from your users, so I think that in this situation (lacking of configuration settings) your best option is to terminate the application with an informative message (name and path of file and reasons to end the app)

Comment: Thank you for your time and answer. May I ask what should I return when path was null to make it work until I set the path? Because now I have on startup page grid which need that connection. Thanks again.

Comment: @Marek, lacking of a connection string in an app that requires a connection to a database is a critical failure. I think you should terminate the interaction with your user.

Comment: However, your error message (directory not found) hints to a possible misconfiguration. You need to address this problem in your installation procedure. (manually or automatically, at the end of the installation that file should be in the correct directory and the web.config correctly configured)

Comment: Thank you for your advice, I tried to search through the internet how it can be done but haven't found any helpful guide. I'm using InstallShield project in Visual Studio for building .exe file. Could you please refer me to some link? Thank you again so much.

Comment: I don't use InstallShield, but I think that it should have a way to sustitute strings in you distributed configuration files. The config file is just an xml file.  So you could distribute your config with the swPath set to a special string (for example swPath=%REPLACE_ME%), then replace the string with an actual path on the target machine....